# Change types programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

If I have two custom UITextField subclasses, such as

```
Class AlphaField: UITextField {
    self.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.alphabet
}

Class NumberField: UITextField {
    self.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
}
```

Can I then assign one of these types to a UITextField based on a statement in the viewDidLoad? For example something like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var someTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if someBool {
        someTextField = AlphaField
    } else {
        someTextField = NumberField
    }
}
```

I should add above is just an example. I have a reason for using subclasses instead of just changing the UIKeyboardType.

Comment: use `extension` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, that will work. Of course you need to initialize them properly:

```
if someBool {
    someTextField = AlphaField(frame: someRect)
} else {
    someTextField = NumberField(frame: someRect)
}
self.view.addSubview(someTextField)
```

This works since `someTextField` is a `UITextField` and can point to any subclass of `UITextField`.

Please note that since you are creating the text field programmatically, there is no reason to make `someTextField` an outlet.